# What is the community-preferred Ruby unit testing framework?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, xunit

In the Java space, JUnit is predominately used and in .NET I believe nUnit is very popular. Is a community agreed upon unit testing framework for the Ruby world?

Background: I ask because I am new to Ruby and want to practice TDD at same time as I learn Ruby. So far I've only played with Test::Unit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can stick to `Test::Unit` or you can have nice extensions to it using [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) or some cool contexts using [Context](https://github.com/jm/context).

On the other side, if you prefer BDD then you can safely stick to [RSpec](http://rspec.info/).

As for for acceptance testing use [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) .

Comment: [MiniTest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) is also becoming a very popular option which combines both Unit and Spec testing styles into one library.

Answer (score 7):

See also [What’s the most commonly used unit testing framework for different types of Ruby applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448783/whats-the-most-commonly-used-unit-testing-framework-for-different-types-of-ruby) question.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular one is [RSpec](http://rspec.info/), although both [expectations](http://expectations.rubyforge.org/) and [test/unit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/) are quite well-known.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [manager](https://rubygems.org/gems/manager) gem that I have developed. It not only is a test framework, but is does documentation as well at the same time.